# How to change default location of WebSphere application server ND v9?

Tags: websphere

By default, WAS is installed at /opt/IBM/

I am using ./imcl to install WAS via terminal. Wanted to understand -> how do I change this default location as I don't have much space left in /opt.

Tried export install_root as well as profile_root. Also tried using -installationDirectory attribute along with ./imcl

Didn't help though..

The command I ran(worked fine for systems having enough /opt space):-

(1) sudo su-

(2) ./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v90_9.0.0.20160526_1854 com.ibm.java.jdk.v8_8.0.3000.20160526_1317 -repositories /home/xyz/WAS/repository.config,/home/xyz/Java8/repository.config -installationDirectory /home/xyz/WebSphere_v9/AppServer -acceptLicense -showProgress -record install_was.xml

I keep getting this error:-

```
CRIMA1179E ERROR: The following errors were generated while installing.
CRIMA1179E ERROR: Available disk space at /opt is insufficient.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link from developer works solved my query.

So I needed to also specify -dataLocation and -sharedResourcesDirectory at the time of installation(starting from InstallationManager). Phew!!

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/184827/installation-manager-error-crima1179e-available-di/

Answer (score 0):

`imcl` takes `-installationDirectory` for the install operation. This applies to all of the "normal" websphere offerings (WAS, Liberty, IHS, PMT) but a few obscure things (Edge Caching Proxy) don't obey it.